# Rollover one div to switch multiple div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Having a problem with using a rollover to bring up text and images in other div tags. So I basically want to write a JavaScript (jQuery) function that says something like:

```
$(.class).mouse enter(function(){
 change (this class) to (this class)
 change (this class) to (this class)
 change (this class) to (this class)

 $(.class).mouse leave(function(){
 change (this class) back to (this class)
 change (this class) back to (this class)
 change (this class) back to (this class)
```

Granted these classes are in different div tags and are not all in the same div tag. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Start by learning jQuery. [try jQuery](http://try.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 2):

This dummy code might be what you need. But I really recommend that you learn jQuery before you use this piece of code.

```
$('.className').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $('.class').removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');
    $('#id').removeClass('oldClass1').addClass('newClass1');
});

$('.className').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $('.class').removeClass('newClass').addClass('oldClass');
    $('#id').removeClass('newClass1').addClass('oldClass1');
});
```

Comment: is this kind of how it is suppose to look like?

Comment: I think so. Change the `.className` `.class` `#id` `oldClass` `newclass` `oldClass1` and `newclass1` to your desired values.